# Why I can make Windows 8 and 8.1 Pro join domain but can't login after?

Tags: windows-8, login, samba, active-directory, windows-domain

Is there any tweak to be done in Windows 8 Pro or Windows 8.1 Pro that makes me be able to login after joining a Samba 4 domain/AD? 
All the other machines with Windows 7 even XP are in the domain and there is no problem when I try to logon.
This is a strange problem because I can join the domain and after the reboot not even my user can logon.

[Edit]
I manage to login by disabling the Netbios. But now only me and one other user can login.
It is very annoying no one else can login when the machine has Windows 8

[Edit]

Is there a way to transform Windows 8 in Windows 7? :D Actually, is there a way to change the authentication method in Windows 8 till we figure it out on the server (if it is really the server)? Because now with all machines coming with Windows 8 is only make us work twice, thrice more, removing and inserting the machine in the domain each time a user tries log in.

Comment: You may try failing back with smb protocol on server, with parameter [server max protocol](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#SERVERMAXPROTOCOL)

Comment: Thanks. The guys tested on Windows 8 and worked but In 8.1 didn't work. Samba 4 seams to be a trick fellow. Thanks very much.

Comment: We've used SMB3 worked for logon using Windows 8 and 8.1 but somehow all users lost their privileges to access the shares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My tests in other systems are working with 4.0.0, 4.0.27, 4.1.6 and 4.1.7 both package and compiled version.

We will migrate that server. Many problems emerge since then. We'll solve it soon now that we have the attention and comprehension of the other sectors, mainly accepting that I.T. guys are not magicians and can't make software work without the adequate hardware.

Using the recommendations from the samba.org site works fine, even some tries it didn't work completely but now works!
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO

Thanks guys for your help.